# Changing a cell value based on today's date

Tags: excel, vba

I have not done VB for excel before, but have experience in some other languages.

I am looking to have the person input the amount in Todays Excess and have it automatically key that amount on another cell based on the date (todays date).

[image]

Comment: OK, so what have you tried? Please include the code you came up with after you did your research in your question and explain the issues you are having with it.

Comment: I have only managed to change the cell value without any if statement as I couldnt get to find the code to select the specific cell that has the same value as todays date.

Comment: And what would you like to achieve? The cell of the 'Excess Cash` column, corresponding to today data in `Date` column?

Comment: So yeah, when someone keys in todays excess amount, the numbers will also be updated on the corresponding dates (which is actually placed in another sheet).

Answer (score 1):

Your sheet structure used for manually input data must keep the date in column A:A, and the values will be input in column B:B

You must open IDE (Alt + F11) and double click the sheet module (where you intend to manually input data) and copy the next code there:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim lastR As Long, rng As Range
   lastR = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lastR)
   If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then'the code runs only for changes in the B:B range, containing data (in A:A)
        Dim rowDate As Long, sh As Worksheet, refDate As Date, rowD As Range
        rowDate = Target.row: refDate = CDate(Target.Offset(0, -1).value)
        Set sh = Worksheets("YourSheeetToBeUpdated") 'Be carefull to change here your sheet name to be updated

        lastR = sh.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR)
        Set rowD = rng.Find(CDate(refDate), , , xlWhole)
        If Not rowD Is Nothing Then
            rowD.Offset(0, 1).value = Target.value
        Else
            MsgBox "The date " & refDate & " could not be found in " & sh.Name
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Please take care to use the name of your sheet to be updated. Change "YourSheeetToBeUpdated" with that specific worksheet name. If you do not understand something, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have editted the stuffs and managed to at least understand what's supposed to be going on.

However, I got a runtime error 13 for this code "refDate = CDate(Target.Offset(0, -1).Value)"

Is it related to string and integers?

Comment: Please test it and let me know if it works as you like. Then, you can put a break on the first line of the code (skipping the declarations line) and input a value on the sheet. Then, pressing F8, it will run line by line. Moving the cursor over the variables, you can see their value...

Comment: Alright, just did everything and the number didnt change on the other sheet. I'm sorry for the trouble but I'm also really lost! T_T

Comment: Firstly, no any problem! Secondly, let us take it step by step: Do you have in the second sheet, in column A:A the same date range? If yes, are they `Date` formatted? If yes, are you sure about that... Try putting a formula in, let us say, "C3" like this `=Day(A3)`. What does it return? In fact, the first step would be to see if your code runs... Put a break on the code in the sheet module. Put the cursor on the second row and press F9. That line will become brown. Then go in Excel sheet and make a change. Are you brought on the specific code line?

Comment: Oh I think I get how the code works! Actually, only the "excess amount" input is on the first sheet. The second sheet is the graph of all the dates and the respective values, based on the first sheet which looks for date on "today's date".

Comment: So, in your second sheet, there must be date in column A:A. Not necessarily to be in the same order. If they would be in the same order, the code can be a little simplified, but in this way it works for any order. Please test it and let me know if it works as you need. If not, let us, start debugging in order to understand where the problem is...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209158/discussion-between-fouzy-fostdecile-and-faneduru).